# Java equivalent of fork in Java task of Ant?

Tags: java, ant, fork

[Ant Java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) provides `fork` parameter, which, by definition *"if enabled triggers the class execution in another VM"*. As we are dealing with a large amount of data, setting this parameter saved us from running out of Java heap space.
We want to be able to do the same through a Java class. What would be the best way to achieve the functionality as provided by `fork`?

Comment: If all you need is more heap than consider using the -Xmx and -Xms options when you launch your app. Maybe you don't need multiple processes, just more memory in the first place. There is added benefit that within the same JVM you can use threads and concurrency primitives.

Comment: Right. We did try that by setting the Xms and Xmx to various values but that did not help. The program eventually crashed after running for different durations, depending upon the values set. Apparently, it does have to do with memory, but we never faced when we called it via Ant (with fork set).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Execute another java process. By using ProcessBuilder class, for example.

http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

You can run as many worker processes as you wish. Make them having a separate main class, doing their tasks from that main class, and quiting when their task is completed.

You'll have to figure out their classpath, and the location of java binary on the system, but that's doable.

I think you can even be notified when they complete via Process.waitFor().

Comment: I htink it would be in the same VM, however.

Comment: Nope, if you run a Process, it's the different VM.

Two different Processes can not share one VM by any means.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the `ant` source code, when `fork` is `true`, then it just wraps an `Execute` task and eventually, the code that gets called is

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
```

Downloading and having a look at the source code for `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java` and `org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute` will give you some great pointers in finding the location of the executable to run in a platform independent way, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can directly use the Ant API...Ant can be directly used in a Java class. The Javadoc is available in their binary distribution.