# How to use threads in Java SE

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857735/understanding-threads)

I have a public class that is implementing a Runnable interface.
So how and where will I use the thread in this class?

```
public class Main implements Runnable {
Thread trun;
public static void looper() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    looper();
}

}
```

Comment: Can you maybe read the documentation, examples and so forth?

Comment: See authentic & genuine Java tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Your class doesn't compile. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ for how to start threads. Google is your friend: google for java threads tutorial, and you'll find this link.

Comment: And get this book: http://jcip.net/

Comment: You are using the "main" thread here already. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very simple tutorial should help you with your issue:
http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4202

Your main method shouldn't implement runnable. A runnable class is to be called (inside your main method for example) (check out the link).

Answer (score 2):

Read [Oracle's Java lesson on Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new MyRunner());
        t.start();
    }
}

public class MyRunner implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        looper();
    }

    public void looper() {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```